# Using a ComboBox to run multiple criteria on a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

The records in my DB can hold information of location in up to three different fields and in three slightly different ways - the first two letters of a reference number (REFVAL), the second as a specific area code (AREA) and the third using values in a field not used for anything else (USE). This situation is due to poor data transfer and should be sorted by pending data cleansing. In the meantime I need to get to the info in whichever field it is in. 
To do this in the SQL query I did this:

```
WHERE ((REFVAL Like 'XX*') OR (AREA Like 'XXXX') OR (USE Like 'XXX'))
```

which works to get to what I need. What I want is a form that will input the criteria into the query when the user selects an option from the combobox:

User selects "Area 1" from the combobox and the query is run using WHERE ((REFVAL Like '01*') OR (AREA Like 'A001') OR (USE Like 'Area01'))

User selects "Area 2" from the combobox and the query is run using WHERE ((REFVAL Like '02*') OR (AREA Like 'A002') OR (USE Like 'Area02')) etc.

I can get the form to feed a single value into the query from the combobox, but am struggling with the multiple values each combobox entry needs to feed back.

I have researched this and found some VB stuff that looks similar but nothing that appears to do exactly what I need. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Graham

Comment: Are you **literally** using that data above, or are those "imaginary" values?  I ask because you could either use a **Case** statement, or you would use variables in your **Select** statement.  I can answer the question better based on your response.

Comment: Also, if you could say how many possible choices are available in the combo box, and give a real example of what the **WHERE** clause would look like for one of them, I can give you some code that will (hopefully) work.

Comment: Hi,  the data  is pretty much as it is there,  yes.  I wanted to be as close to the real situation as possible and that is pretty much what I have to clean up! All the fields are in the same table. There are six areas for the combobox to handle plus I would like to include a wildcard to catch them all if possible.  I am using Access 2010 if that makes a difference.  Thanks for your time on this.